# How to redirect to url when this progess-bar reached 100%

Tags: javascript, redirect, progress-bar

I'm new in JS and I used this progess-bar and I stuck to redirect to a link after it finished loading ... I'm sure that its small thing but I tried and I still unsuccess

the example here:
[Demo](https://jsbin.com/vohiwu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: making a guess - there is complete state at the end of the code (`complete: function() {//here code on complete}`) - there you write in `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

Comment: didnt work: $('#time_session').radialProgress("init", {'size': 45, 'fill': 2})
        .radialProgress("to", {'perc': 100, 'time': 1000,
         complete: function() {
          window.location.replace("stackoverflow.com");
         }
        });

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are trying to hook an event `complete`. After inspecting the code, there is no trigger for that event ! However, I added one. It will be triggered when the loader complete loading (100%):

```
//Trigger the complete callback when finished
(options.complete || $.noop()).call(this);
```

The same for the step event:

```
//Trigger the step callback
(options.complete || $.noop()).call(this);
```

Please check this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wululilofo/1/edit?html,js,output) to see where I've added this two lines.

Now add `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/");` in your complete callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s an example that might help you.
Remove the alert and put in your URL after the progress bar.

Good luck and mark me as an answer if this helps you

```js
var time = 10000; // 10 secs 
var steps = 50; // Five per second 
var step = 1;

function progress() { 
var bar = document.getElementById( "barwrap"); 
var aStep = (bar.offsetWidth -2) /steps;// 2px border removed from width 
var x = Math.round( aStep *step); 
var outer = document.getElementById( "outer"); 
var inner = document.getElementById( "inner");

// Work out seconds based on % progress from current step 
var secs = (( time /1000) -Math.floor( ( step /steps) *10));

inner.style.width = x +"px"; 
step++;

// If 0 seconds, display waiting message instead 
outer.firstChild.innerHTML = ( secs? secs +" seconds...": "Please Wait..."); 
// Match text 
inner.firstChild.innerHTML = outer.firstChild.innerHTML;

if( step > steps) redir(); 
else setTimeout( "progress();", time /steps); 
}

function redir() { 
alert( "Redirecting now!"); //Replace for your URL
}
```

```css
* { font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; }

#wrap { margin-top: 50px;text-align: center; }

#barwrap { 
position: relative; /* to contain outer */ 
margin: 0 auto; /* to centre */ 
width: 250px;height: 20px; /* size of our bar - required */ 
text-align: left; 
font-weight: bold; 
border: 1px solid black; 
}

#barwrap P { /* to contain text */ 
margin: 0; /* FF needs this or text drops below bar */ 
width: 250px; /* use this node to position text */ 
text-align: center; 
}

#barwrap #outer { /* bar 'background' */ 
position: absolute; 
width: 100%; height: 100%; /* match parent size */ 
background: lightgreen; 
color: green; /* original colour of text */ 
}

#barwrap #inner { 
position: relative; /* otherwise outer hides us */ 
width: 0; height: 100%; /* match parent */ 
overflow: hidden; /* to hide new text/prevent it wrapping */ 
background: green; 
color: lightgreen; /* colour of changed text */ 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test Page</title> 
  </head>

<body>

<div id='wrap'> 
Progress: 
<div id='barwrap'> <!-- P wrappers for text positioning --> 
<div id='outer'><p></p></div> <!-- original colour/text --> 
<div id='inner'><p></p></div> <!-- new colour/text --> 
</div>

<br> 
<a href='#' onClick='progress();'>Click here to start bar (only once please, you'll break it)</a> 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

More information here:
https://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3321308.htm

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar library you are using does not appear to support any events, so the only way I can see to tell that is done, is to read its private data manually and then do what you want based on that.

This is not something I would suggest doing, I would extend their library to support callbacks or find a new library, but this would work for a temporary solution.

```
var id = null;
var checkIfDone = function() { 
    var perc = $('#time_session').radialProgress().data('__radialProgress').perc;
    if ( perc >= 100) { 
        console.log('done');
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
        // this isn't going to work @ jsbin.com because its executed in a
        // frame, but you can see that it tries to execute it in the console
    }
    else {
        console.log('not done yet, only ' + perc);
        id = setTimeout(checkIfDone,1000); // check every second until done
    } 
 };
checkIfDone();
```

Comment: Ismail's post is the better way to do it and what I suggest you go with.  Just be aware, every time you update that library, you'll have to add your customization back in.